# Simple structs: advantages/disadvantages of using non-static member initialization, aggregate initialization or constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

As of C++11, there seem to be three viable ways to define simple structs. (I know that in C++14 option A and B can be combined, but my question relates to C++11).

```
// non-static member initialization
struct PointA
{
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
};
PointA pA1;
PointA pA2; pA2.x = 2.0; pA2.y = -1.0;  // can this be made more elegantly ?

// aggregate initialization
struct PointB
{
    double x;
    double y;
};
PointB pB1 = { 0.0,  0.0 };  // or does it suffice to write PointB pB1; here?
PointB pB2 = { 2.0, -1.0 };

// constructor
struct PointC
{
    double x;
    double y;
    PointC(double initX = 0.0, double initY = 0.0) : x(initX), y(initY) { }
};
PointC pC1;
PointC pC2( 2.0, -1.0 );
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using each of them ? And which should be preferred in which circumstances in C++11 ? (and would this change if C++14 combined member and aggregate initialization was available ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++14, I prefer

```
struct PointA
{
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
};
```

which allows

```
PointA pA1; // {0., 0.}
PointA pA2 = { 2.0, -1.0 };
```

but also

```
PointA pA3 = { 2.0 }; // {2., 0.}
```

which may be undesirable.

In c++11 (or if you want to forbid some constructors):

```
struct PointD
{
    PointD() : PointD(0, 0) {}
    PointD(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    double x;
    double y;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A constructor's job is to establish a user defined **class invariant**.

If there is no user defined class invariant then a constructor's job is just to make sure that all data members have valid values, i.e. are not **indeterminate** (such values can lead to Undefined Behavior when used).

When the only class invariant is that “data members have valid values”, the secondary job, then a constructor is only needed as a way to make the class idiot-proof, so that a novice cannot use it to declare an uninitialized variable. But this has the cost of making the class non-POD. These concerns must be balanced, but it's worth keeping in mind that you can always define a POD class plus a derived class that has constructor.

---

Regarding the first code example,

```
struct Point
{
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
};

Point a1;
Point a2; a2.x = 2.0; a2.y = -1.0;  // can this be made more elegantly ?
```

Due to the data member initializers this class effectively has a constructor like:

```
Point::Point()
    : x( 0.0 ), y( 0.0 )
{}
```

And this prevents compilation with Visual C++ 2015 of a declaration like

```
Point point = { 5.0, 6.0 };
```

The declaration is accepted by MinGW g++ 5.1.0. I don't know the formal of this. But as a matter of practical programming, the different compiler behaviors means that ***currently* there is no more elegant way to do the commented declaration of `a2` in your example**.

---

Regarding the second code example,

```
// aggregate initialization
struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};
Point b1 = { 0.0,  0.0 };  // or does it suffice to write PointB pB1; here?
Point b2 = { 2.0, -1.0 };
```

Whether it suffices to write just `Point b1;` depends:

- If this is a namespace scope declaration then `b1` is zero-initialized first of all, so there it's OK.
- If this is a local declaration then there is no automatic zero-initialization, and so omitting the explicit initialization would give you indeterminate values, leading to UB.

However, you can reduce the declaration to just

```
Point b1 = {};
```

or

```
Point b1{};
```

depending on your general conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on default constructor.

You can simplify any constructor(s) you define.

No it doesn't suffice to write PointB pB1. But you can just put 
PointB pB1{{},{}};

Comment: Are you sure only `PointB pB1;` guarantees `pB1.x` and `pB1.y` will be initialized as `0.0`?